# Merge arrays under same key

Tags: json, jq

I have two files containing objects. The fields of each object are arrays of objects. I would like to merge the object arrays by each key.

I tried getting a list of all keys by `jq -s '.[0] * .[1] | to_entries[].key ' file1.json file2.json`. I 'm not sure how you would match the keys from .[1] to .[0] once you have captured the object arrays.

`file1.json`

```
{
    "foo": [
        {
            "nested": "object"
        }
    ],
    "bar": [
        {
            "nested": "object.bar"
        }
    ]

}
```

`file2.json`

```
{
    "foo": [
        {
            "nested": "object.foo2"
        }
    ],
    "baz": [
        {
            "nested": "object.baz"
        }
    ]

}
```

`merged.json`

```
{
    "foo": [
        {
            "nested": "object"
        },
        {
            "nested": "object.foo2"
        },

    ]
    "bar": [
        {
            "nested": "object.bar"
        }
    ]
    "baz": [
        {
            "nested": "object.baz"
        }
    ]

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
map(to_entries) | add | group_by(.key) | map({ key: (.[0].key), value:([.[].value | add]) }) | from_entries
```

[Try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/xe0rm1mOna).

`map(to_entries)` change each of your files into an array of key/value pairs.

`add` merge those two arrays into one.

`group_by(.key)` changes the content of the array into multiple arrays that regroup the objects with the same key.

`map({ key: (.[0].key), value:([.[].value | add]) })` transforms those arrays into an object with a key/value pair whose key is the original key and the value is the merged values of the different objects with that key.

`from_entries` recreates an object from the array of key/value objects.

Answer (score 2):

Using nested `reduce`s:

```
reduce inputs as $in (.;
  reduce ($in | keys_unsorted[]) as $k (.;
    .[$k] += $in[$k]
  )
)
```

[jqplay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1j36HphMRb)